# What is the most effective way to delete entites that satisfy a condition from a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

AFAIK, there isn't a direct way to delete entities using a predicate such as

```
DbSet.RemoveWhere(() => {})
```

I tried a few ways to delete and don't know which is the most efficient way to do it. Could you point me in the right direction?

The first and most basic thing I tried is:

```
_context.Users.RemoveRange(_context.Users.Where(u => u.Name.Equals("John")));
```

which loads the user to the memory before deletion. I don't like this approach. The second way I tried is using the `Z.EntityFramework.Plus` package:

```
_context.Users.Where(u => u.Name.Equals("John")).Delete()
```

which claims to delete objects without loading them but I don't know if this is better then the first way. Also this feels wrong as the efcore should have a proper way to do this. The third attempt I made was something like this:

```
_context.Users.Where(u => u.Name.Equals("John")).ForEachAsync(u => _context.Users.Remove(u));
```

I don't know if this loads the users into the memory and it has a nasty Async in there. It also gives the following exception:

```
"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."
```

Comment: any reason you need to involve the ORM in this at all? it kinda feels like this could be done in SQL far more effectively, i.e. `"delete from Users where Name = @name"`; the db-context has APIs to allow you to call parameterized raw SQL fairly easily

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess I am not familiarized enough with this. This is most probably the thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ExecuteSqlRaw` is more appropriate for you:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = @p0", "John");
```

Generally `Remove` and `RemoveRange` are suitable for situations which you already have `Primary Key` (usually `Id`) of objects, in those cases you can do something like this:

```
_context.Users.Remove(new User {Id = id});
```

Comment: I would rather use the external package than the raw query. It looks hard to maintain later on. Also, what happens if the id is not unique as in my case?

Comment: @M.Azyoksul `Id` was sample here. I mean `Primary Key` which have to be unique. I'm agree with taking care of code. But you should profile that and be sure that it doesn't load items to delete.